# Convert local time to CET using momentJs

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

To convert local time to UTC is easy:

```
var localTime = "2018-02-27 11:00";    
moment(localTime).utc().format(); // result: "2018-02-27T09:00:00Z"
```

However I'm not sure if there is a straightforward way to convert my local time to CET (or other timezone such as EST, WEST)

I know that I can do something like this

```
moment(localTime).tz("Europe/Berlin").format();
```

which seems to return what I want but still unsure if thats the correct way or not?

Comment: Yes, it is the the correct way to convert a moment object to `Europe/Berlin` timezone using [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/).

Comment: ok so what if I want to convert to EST or WEST?

Comment: Then you pass whichever [time zone identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) you want.   (Note that abbreviations are not generally valid identifiers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/)

since it accounts for daylight saving.

```
moment(momentTZ().tz("Europe/Berlin")).format();
```

If you do not mind for daylight saving moment itself is fine.